# Difference in the amount of decimal numbers between double and long double

Tags: c, floating-point

What’s the difference between the amount of decimal values in a *double* data type and a *long double* data type in c?

Comment: the representation in memory, double data represents by 8 bytes while long double by 16 bytes which can represent much larger numbers than regular double variable

Comment: C is not required to follow [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), but many implementations do (to some extent).

Comment: Remember that these numbers of digits are *approximate*.  Most machines use binary floating point, not decimal.  So while type `double` can distinguish between, say, the numbers 1.000000000000001 and 1.000000000000002, it does not represent those numbers using those decimal digits, and it cannot represent either of them exactly.

Comment: @MichaelGabbay: Sizes of the `double` and `long double` types vary between C implementations. The C standard does not require `double` to have eight bytes or `long double` to have 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` - 15 decimal places

`long double` - 19 decimal places (on systems where 80-bit format is used)

80-bit is the most common format, but is not available on all systems.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Real_floating_types

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

Comment: Good suggestion.  Revised answer.

Comment: slide rules: 3 digits. Good enough to get people to the Moon.

Answer (score 3):

C does not require a difference in the amount of significant decimal digits between `double` and `long double`.  They may be the same.

To report the number of significant decimal digits a floating point type can *at least* faithfully encode, see [`xxx_DIG`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_floating_point_types).

```
#include <float.h>

printf("long double %d\n", LDBL_DIG); // min: 10, Typically 15, 18 or 33
printf("double %d\n", DBL_DIG);       // min: 10, Often 15
printf("float %d\n", FLT_DIG);        // min:  6, Often 6
```